# How To User Fetch Friends Data Using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

What i Need:

- i need to fetch my friends like email ,id , name .
- i have tried using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/1456/?method=GET&path=me&version=v2.1.
- url is like graph.facebook.com/v2.1/me .
  data

  ```
   {
   "id": "77", 
  "email": "af55@gmail.com", 
   "first_name": "Mo", 
   "gender": "male", 
    "interested_in": [
   "female"
  ], 
   "last_name": "f", 
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/777/", 
  "locale": "en_GB", 
  "name": "singh", 
  "timezone": 5.5, 
  "updated_time": "2014-08-18T05:34:55+0000", 
  "verified": true
  }
  ```
- but making call graph.facebook.com/v2.1/user 
  Error

  ```
   {
   "error": {
   "message": "(#803) Cannot query users by their username (user)", 
   "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 803
   }
   }
  ```

  - i have refer the url https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user.
  - i  have tried to solve by  go ->getACEESS TOKEN->check on permissions->email->user_friends.
    but still i cannot fetch url through user.
  - making call with me/friends

    ```
        {
        "data": [
          {
         "name": "Ashwani Gaur", 
           "id": "62036"
         }, 
        {
        "name": "Shobhit Puri", 
        "id": "131"
         }, 
        {
          "name": "Rahul Raman", 
         "id": "10007"
       }, 
        {
          "name": "Piyush Agarwal", 
          "id": "800899"
        }, 
     {
      "name": "Neeraj Yadav", 
       "id": "10000"
     }
     ], 
              "paging": {
              "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/777009872366669/friends?limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=enc_AeytV0frT0k1mTj0ZfZRTxPsdSP3TVT_Qd-I1Aoc8vA8YseN4Rr8Vg5n6RgECxsd6RXaVNL8fJ0iaI79qEW7K8nw"
    }, 
        "summary": {
       "total_count": 383
          }
          }
    ```

    - i need id, name, email, friend personal_info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since April 2014 (v2.0), there are no friend permissions anymore and it´s not possible to get user data from people who don´t use the App. See the changelog for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

The docs are a bit misleading, you can only use /me to get data of the user who is logged in at the moment.

**Update:**
By requesting `/me/friends`, you get all the friends using the App. But as i said in my first sentence, there are no friend permissions anymore. You will only get ID and name of your friends, nothing else. Even if your friend authorized your App, you can ONLY get more data with his own session and by calling `/me`. The email permission only gives you access to the email of the user who is logged in, not access to the emails of all his friends, of course.

You can only store the email after authorizing a user, that is the only way for other users to get the email of his friends - at least the ones who authorized your App too.

Comment: please help in issue when requesting a call me/friends then i only get id,name of friends instead of i have set permissions->getaccesstoken->extendedpermissions email +user_friends.

Comment: check out my answer, it´s all in there. you can´t get those things from friends, only from the user who is logged in at the moment. would be weird if you could get the email from another person, zero privacy.

Comment: i have added more in my question , you have not updated yur answer

Comment: the answer is still correct, i guess you did not check out the changelog. anyway, i will add some more info :/

Comment: it´s not possible, you can only store the email for authorized users, see my updated answer.

Comment: ok got it , but could we fetch email of other user from its id is it possible sr

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61656/discussion-between-user3785613-and-luschn).

Comment: NO, this is NOT (and was NEVER) possible via the Graph API, as @luschn said

Comment: there is no need to chat, everything you need to know is in the answer already. of course you cannot get the email of friends, that would be a major privacy issue.

Comment: i dn"t know why my post mark negative unless facebook doc mislead developer .this is bug in there docs